# highlight matched data only works for single value matched

Tags: php

As the following code show , i want to print the `$input` but with highlight matched values from `$match`

It works but it highlight only single value and the others are not

```
<?php
$input = Array ( 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5294518/' , 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6924650/' , 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7313348/' , 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9134216/' , 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9586294/' , 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3256226/' );
$match = Array ( 'tt3256226' , 'tt7313348' , 'tt5294518' ) ;

foreach ($input as $index => $row){

    foreach ($match as $key => $value){

    }
    echo "<div>" , ($index + 1) , '- ', (str_replace($match,"<strong><font color='blue'>" . $value . "</strong></font>",$row)) , "</div>";
}
```

here is the output in the following image
[https://i.ibb.co/DMDpgzd/Untitled.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oFOT.jpg)

**Here is the real complete code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Check IMDB</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <form method="POST" action="">
            <input type="submit" value="&nbsp;&nbsp;Check IMDB&nbsp;&nbsp;">
            <div>
                <textarea style="width: 50%; margin-top:7px; height: 150px;" name="urlbox" placeholder="Add IMDB links here (one per line)"></textarea>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>

<?php
$imdblink = "";
$imdblink = $_POST['urlbox'];

?>

<?php
set_time_limit(0);
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php');

global $wpdb;

$array = explode(PHP_EOL, $imdblink);

$matches = preg_match_all('(tt[0-9]+)', $imdblink, $imdbid);
$imdbid = $imdbid[0];
$imdbid = preg_filter('/^/', '\'', $imdbid);
$imdbid = preg_filter('/$/', '\'', $imdbid);
$imdbids = join(',', $imdbid);
$imdbids = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE 'imdb' AND meta_value IN ($imdbids)");
$imdbids = array_column($imdbids, "meta_value");

foreach ($array as $index => $url) {
    if (in_array(basename($url), $imdbids)) {
        $url = '<a href="' . $url . '" class="strong blue">' . $url . '</a>';
    }
    echo "<div>" , ($index + 1) , "- {$url}</div>\n";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

**Input in text area**

```
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5294518/
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6924650/
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7313348/
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9134216/
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9586294/
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3256226/
```

**Output of $array**

```
Array ( [0] => https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5294518/ [1] => https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6924650/ [2] => https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7313348/ [3] => https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9134216/ [4] => https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9586294/ [5] => https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3256226/ )
```

**Output of $imdbids**

```
Array ( [0] => tt3256226 [1] => tt7313348 [2] => tt5294518 )
```

Comment: I changed my question and add more details about my issue @mickmackusa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `preg_match_all()` to extract/isolate the submitted ttids only (no need to explode).  Writing a pattern with a capture group (`()`) will unnecessarily bloat/double the amount of data in the matches array.  You intend to use the entire (fullstring) matched string each time, this will be stored in the `[0]` subarray of the matches array.  The pattern needs to match two literal `t` characters, then seven or eight digits -- this what `tt\d{7,8}` does.
- Then construct your query's IN parameters by hardcoding the first and last single quotes and using `','` as the joining glue -- this will sufficiently quote-wrap each matched ttid.  Then the result set's `meta_value` column will act as the lookup array while you iterate the earlier matched ttids.  If there is a match between a ttid entered and the lookup, convert the entry into a clickable link.

  ```
  $input = 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5294518/
  https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6924650/
  https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7313348/
  https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9134216/
  https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9586294/
  https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3256226/';

  if (!preg_match_all('~tt\d{7,8}~', $input, $ttids)) {
      echo "no ttids found";
  } else {
      $resultSet = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'imdb' AND meta_value IN ('" . implode("','", $ttids[0]) . "');");
      $foundInDatabase = array_column($resultSet, "meta_value");
      foreach ($ttids[0] as $index => $ttid) {
          if (in_array($ttid, $foundInDatabase)) {
              $ttid = "<a class=\"strong blue\" href=\"https://www.imdb.com/title/{$ttid}/\">{$ttid}</a>";
          }
          echo "<div>" , ($index + 1) , "- {$ttid}</div>";
      }
  }
  ```

Additional notes...

IMDB tt ids will have 7 to 8 digits and will only occur once in a url.

Relevant Resources:

- https://github.com/tboothman/imdbphp/issues/163 (7 or 8 digits)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:IMDb_title

You should only use LIKE in sql queries if you need to leverage wildcard characters (`_`, `%`). When making literal matches just use `=`.

When building your html, I'll advise you to move away from simple `<br>` elements and start encapsulating your content in meaningful tags that can be styled by an external stylesheet (this is why I've added the `class` attribute to the divs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your information and explanation but the imdb ids

Comment: I can't edit my comment here which is strange, only delete button is available

anyway, the imdb ids are stored in my database as `tt0426883`
not as urls, that's why i build my preg-match as `(tt[0-9]+)`

the input which is `$imdblink` are URLS like this 

    https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0426883/
    https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0158997/

so, i need to highlight the matched values found in my database which is `$imdbids` and print the links again `$imdblink` but with highlighted values from `$imdbids`

Comment: I changed my question and add more details about my issue, Thanks @mickmackusa

Comment: Thanks a lot for keep support my question, really appreciated - 
although your code is working 100% but when i try to embed it in my php file  - it match the first value only
i updated my question with the real code in my php @mickmackusa

Comment: Works like charm, Thanks a million
two notes: first, this code `{$ttid}` for building links didn't work and gave me an error but i replaced with `'.$ttid.'` and it works fine, second, what is the different between my preg_match `(tt[0-9]+)` and yours `~tt\d{7,8}~` @mickmackusa